# How to find eigenvectors and choosing free variable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have this matrix:
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 0 \\
    1 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
and I have to find the eigenvectors of the upper matrix.

As usual, I found the eigenvalues: *x$_{1}$*= 2, *x$_{2}$*= 1, *x$_{3}$*= 0.
The associated eigenvectors are:
$$     
    \begin{bmatrix}   
    1 \\                     
    1 \\               
    0 \\                     
    \end{bmatrix}        
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    0 \\
    1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
    -1 \\
    1 \\
    0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Due to an exercise I found, I have to tell if the vector:
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    2 \\
    -2 \\
    0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
is also an eigenvector.

To find the third eigenvector I used *y* (in *x*, *y* and *z*) as the free variable. Does it change if I use the *x* as free variable in order to invert the first and the second coordinates of the vector in question? So I could find an eigenvector which is a multiple of the last vector I wrote, which is also an eigenvector.
Is it correct or the last vector can't be considered an eigenvector?

Comment: The last vector is an eigenvector. If a matrix $A $ has an eigenvalue $\lambda$ with the associated eigenvector $v $, Then any non-zero scaler of $v$ is also an eigenvector of $A$ with the associated eigenvalue $\lambda $ (easy exercise to try).

Comment: Your question regarding free variables is not clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

The way you *find* the eigenvectors is irrelevant here. Since $\begin{bmatrix}-1&1&0\end{bmatrix}^T$ is an eigenvector, then automatically $\begin{bmatrix}2&-2&0\end{bmatrix}^T$ is also an eigenvector, since$$\begin{bmatrix}2\\-2\\0\end{bmatrix} =(-2)\times\begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Thank you! My bad error...

Answer (score 0):

Every nonzero scalar multiple of an eigenvector is also an eigenvector: If $Av=\lambda v$, then $A(cv)=c(Av)=c(\lambda v)=\lambda(cv).$

However, you can determine whether or not $[2,-2,0]^T$ is an eigenvector of $A$ without doing any of that other work. Simply multiply it by $A$ and see what you get: $$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\\1&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}2\\-2\\0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix} = 0\begin{bmatrix}2\\-2\\0\end{bmatrix}$$ so by definition, this is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $0$.